# Какие существуют альтернативы методу Bitmap SetPixel();?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Я знаю, что есть такой метод в классе Bitmap как `setpixel(x,y,color);`
Какие ещё существуют подобные способы рисования пикселями?

Comment: что имеется ввиду под: _способы рисования пикселями_?

Comment: @Grundy нужен метод, идентично работающий также как и setpixel();, то есть устанавливающий пиксель по координатам

Comment: если нужен SetPixel - значит надо использовать SetPixel - если при использовании SetPixel возникла какая-то проблема стоит задать отдельный вопрос. С описанием проблемы и задачей которую хотел решить.

Comment: Ваш вопрос слишком размытый. Вы не могли бы описать проблему более подробно? Если вы не уверены, как это сделать, сделайте мне пинг в [С# чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26962/c-net--)

Comment: `SetPixel` работает очень медленно. Это единственная причина, почему можно захотеть его не использовать. Нужна скорость - используем [LockBits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5ey6h79d(v=vs.110).aspx) и вручную работаем с байтами.

Comment: Не верится, что ваша проблема из-за `SetPixel`. Думаю, что проблема в другом месте, а вы чините не то, что сломано.

Answer (score 1):

Они и не нужны. На основе SetPixel Можно построить методы для рисования чего угодно.

Comment: мне нужен похожий метод для рисования пикселями, но не setpixel(); класса bitmap

Comment: Что значит похожий?

Comment: с тем же принципом работы, то есть установкой пикселей

Comment: Просто именно с этим методом и классом возникла проблема, так что использовать его не вариант, нужна альтернатива

Comment: Какая именно проблема?

Comment: Её я уже пытался решить, задавал вопросы, никак не получалось, поэтому тот участок кода я стёр (неработающий), пытаюсь найти альтернативный способ